# Not able to use the Firebase-UI snapshot releases

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I would like to try out the Firebase-UI 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT release but cannot get this working.

In my main build file, I added the following repo:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local' } //for FirebaseUI snapshots
    }
}'
```

In my build file, I switch the dependencies as follows:

```
project.ext.firebase_ui = '3.4.0-SNAPSHOT'
//project.ext.firebase_ui = '3.3.1'
```

The dependencies are:

```
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:${project.ext.firebase_ui}"
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:${project.ext.firebase_ui}"
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:${project.ext.firebase_ui}"
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:${project.ext.firebase_ui}"
```

According to the documentation here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#snapshot-builds this should do the trick, but I'm not able to get the build running:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.
      > Could not get resource 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local/com/firebaseui/firebase-ui-database/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/firebase-ui-database-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local/com/firebaseui/firebase-ui-database/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/firebase-ui-database-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: 
> Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.
      > Could not get resource 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local/com/firebaseui/firebase-ui-firestore/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/firebase-ui-firestore-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local/com/firebaseui/firebase-ui-firestore/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/firebase-ui-firestore-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: 
> Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.
      > Could not get resource 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local/com/firebaseui/firebase-ui-storage/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/firebase-ui-storage-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local/com/firebaseui/firebase-ui-storage/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/firebase-ui-storage-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: 
> Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.
      > Could not get resource 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local/com/firebaseui/firebase-ui-auth/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/firebase-ui-auth-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local/com/firebaseui/firebase-ui-auth/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/firebase-ui-auth-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, that was our bad. I've already submitted a PR to update the instructions, but the correct maven repo is this one:

```
maven { url 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }
```

BTW, we're currently working on 4.0 which supports Firestore 16.0, adds a paging adapter, and kills all the deprecated stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now testing the 4.0 release. Looks very promising!